# How to set option selected when using jqtransform on select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jqtransform

How to set option selected when using jqtransform on select element.

I'm using jqtransform for my form , and I want to set appropriate option value to be selected when I'm retrieving saved data from database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you would set the value of select the same way as without using the jqTransform.

E.g.

```
$('#mySelect').val('myVal');
```

**Edit:**

Well, this is really ugly but should work:

```
var mySelect = $('#mySelect');

//find the current selected option
var myOption = mySelect.find('option[value='+mySelect.val()+']');

//find the index of that option
var index = $('#mySelect option').index(myOption);

//trigger the click on the corresponding jqTranfsform element
mySelect.prev('ul').find('li').eq(index).find('a').click();
```

Comment: no , it is not working with jqTransform, otherwise itis working fine .

Comment: it (still) works, but why not get the index by
`var index = mySelect[0].selectedIndex`. That saves an extra line

Answer (score 3):

You can call onchange event. jqtransform has change() method.

```
$('#mySelect').val('myVal').trigger('change');
```

It work's :)